# Snake Game... Adding snake body function malfunctioning

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a snake game in visual studio in visual basic.

The playing field is a 2D Array of PictureBoxes. My Snake is a 1D array as type Point. The snake array is called 'Snake'.

When the form loads, Snake(0) is set as New Point(1, 1). I have created a sub routine that moves the snake depending on the arrow key the user presses. This is under a timer. Snake(0) (The snake head) is set to equal Snake(0) + direction (direction is a variable altered by the arrow key that the user presses, eg. when up is pressed direction is set to x: 0 and y: -1)

When snake(0) hits a piece of food, the amount of elements in the snake array is set to the length of the array. EG(If snake(0) = foodPosition Then ReDim Preserve snake(snake.Length) End If)

I have created a loop, also under the timer, to make the body of the snake follow the head (eg. snake(2) = snake(1) and snake(1) = snake(0) but can't get it to work)

Code:

```
Public Class frmPlayfield

    'Food Creating and Grow Snake Variables
    Dim randF As New Random

    Dim foodPointX As Integer = randF.Next(0, 32)
    Dim foodPointY As Integer = randF.Next(0, 32)

    'Play Field Variables
    Dim playMaxWidth As Integer = 32
    Dim playMaxHeight As Integer = 32
    Dim boxSize As Integer = 16                                'Size of PictureBox
    Dim boxArray(,) As PictureBox                              'PictureBox Array
    'Snake Stuff Variable
    Dim snake(1) As Point                                      'Snake array

    Dim direction As New Point(1, 0)                           'Direction for snake movement

    Private Sub frmPlayfield_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ReDim boxArray(playMaxWidth, playMaxHeight)
        For x As Integer = 0 To playMaxWidth
            For y As Integer = 0 To playMaxHeight
                boxArray(x, y) = New PictureBox
                boxArray(x, y).Width = boxSize
                boxArray(x, y).Height = boxSize
                boxArray(x, y).Top = y * boxSize
                boxArray(x, y).Left = x * boxSize
                boxArray(x, y).Visible = True
                boxArray(x, y).BackColor = Color.White
                boxArray(x, y).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                Me.Controls.Add(boxArray(x, y))
            Next
        Next
        Me.ClientSize = New Size((playMaxWidth + 1) * boxSize, (playMaxHeight + 1) * boxSize)
        snake(0) = New Point(1, 1) 'Creates snake head
        boxArray(foodPointX, foodPointY).BackColor = Color.Red
    End Sub

    Private Function createBox(x As Integer, y As Integer, bSize As Integer) As PictureBox
        Dim tempBox As New PictureBox
        tempBox.Width = bSize
        tempBox.Height = bSize
        tempBox.Top = y * bSize
        tempBox.Left = x * bSize
        tempBox.Visible = True
        tempBox.BackColor = Color.White
        tempBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Me.Controls.Add(tempBox)
        Return tempBox
    End Function

    Private Sub Food()
        If snake(0).X = foodPointX And snake(0).Y = foodPointY Then
            ReDim Preserve snake(snake.Length)                           'Increases the amount of elements in the snake array.
            For j As Integer = 0 To 0
                foodPointX = randF.Next(0, 32)
                foodPointY = randF.Next(0, 32)
                boxArray(foodPointX, foodPointY).BackColor = Color.Red
            Next
        End If
        For h As Integer = snake.Length - 1 To snake.GetUpperBound(0)
            snake(h) = snake(snake.Length - 2)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBoundsAndMovement()
        For i As Integer = 0 To snake.GetUpperBound(0)
            boxArray(snake(i).X, snake(i).Y).BackColor = Color.White 'Loop to change the whole snake black
        Next
        snake(1) = snake(0)
        snake(0) = snake(0) + direction
        If snake(0).X > playMaxWidth Then
            snake(0).X -= (playMaxWidth + 1)
        End If
        If snake(0).X < 0 Then
            snake(0).X += (playMaxWidth + 1)
        End If                                                       'Four If statements to check if the snake has gone outside the play area.
        If snake(0).Y > playMaxWidth Then
            snake(0).Y -= (playMaxWidth + 1)
        End If
        If snake(0).Y < 0 Then
            snake(0).Y += (playMaxWidth + 1)
        End If
        For k As Integer = 0 To snake.GetUpperBound(0)
            boxArray(snake(k).X, snake(k).Y).BackColor = Color.Black 'Loop to make the whole snake black
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub timGameTick_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timGameTick.Tick
        Food()
        CheckBoundsAndMovement()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmPlayfield_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown 'Subroutine for direction
        Select Case (e.KeyCode)
            Case Keys.Up
                direction = New Point(0, -1)
            Case Keys.Down
                direction = New Point(0, 1)
            Case Keys.Left
                direction = New Point(-1, 0)
            Case Keys.Right
                direction = New Point(1, 0)
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

This works fine after I eat the first piece of food. The snake of length 2 is increased to length 3. But when I eat another piece of food the end of the snake is left behind at the spot where the food was eaten.

Comment: It might be helpful on this occasion if you could edit your post to include all your code so that we can replicate the problem. It shouldn't be too long to include here. Thanks

Comment: Ok will do no worries

Comment: If you're putting this in visual studio don't forget to add the timer, called timGameTick

Comment: I'm looking at the code, but I have to go to work. I'll look at it again tonight(late) but maybe someone else will find the answer before I get chance.

Comment: Thanks tons, legend!!

Comment: Would you mind sharing what solution you used to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - It looks like I found the problems -

First off - you defined the `snake` array as `Dim snake (1) As Point` this created the array with two elements instead of 1

Next, in your `Food` sub, the loop to roll the pixels back along the snake should be done every time the snake moves, not just when food is eaten. So I moved it into the `CheckBoundsAndMovement` sub to replace line 4 of that sub which only copied the location of the head to the next point back rather than the whole snake. But of course trying to execute the loop when the length of the snake was only one pixel would result in an out of range exception on the array, so added an `If` statement to only execute the loop if the length of `snake` is more than 1.

Also the direction of the loop in your code was in increasing order. To do it properly it should be in decreasing order. This way, the loop overwrites the point representing the end of the tail with the next point forward and so on. Finally, the new location for the head is entered into `snake(0)`

So - here it is -

```
Public Class frmPlayfield
    'Food Creating and Grow Snake Variables
    Dim randF As New Random

    Dim foodPointX As Integer = randF.Next(0, 32)
    Dim foodPointY As Integer = randF.Next(0, 32)

    'Play Field Variables
    Dim playMaxWidth As Integer = 32
    Dim playMaxHeight As Integer = 32
    Dim boxSize As Integer = 16                                'Size of PictureBox
    Dim boxArray(,) As PictureBox                              'PictureBox Array
    'Snake Stuff Variable
    Dim snake(0) As Point                                      'Snake array
    Dim direction As New Point(1, 0)                           'Direction for snake movement

    Private Sub frmPlayfield_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ReDim boxArray(playMaxWidth, playMaxHeight)
        For x As Integer = 0 To playMaxWidth
            For y As Integer = 0 To playMaxHeight
                boxArray(x, y) = New PictureBox
                boxArray(x, y).Width = boxSize
                boxArray(x, y).Height = boxSize
                boxArray(x, y).Top = y * boxSize
                boxArray(x, y).Left = x * boxSize
                boxArray(x, y).Visible = True
                boxArray(x, y).BackColor = Color.White
                boxArray(x, y).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                Me.Controls.Add(boxArray(x, y))
            Next
        Next
        Me.ClientSize = New Size((playMaxWidth + 1) * boxSize, (playMaxHeight + 1) * boxSize)
        snake(0) = New Point(1, 1) 'Creates snake head
        boxArray(foodPointX, foodPointY).BackColor = Color.Red
    End Sub

    Private Function createBox(x As Integer, y As Integer, bSize As Integer) As PictureBox
        Dim tempBox As New PictureBox
        tempBox.Width = bSize
        tempBox.Height = bSize
        tempBox.Top = y * bSize
        tempBox.Left = x * bSize
        tempBox.Visible = True
        tempBox.BackColor = Color.White
        tempBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Me.Controls.Add(tempBox)
        Return tempBox
    End Function

    Private Sub Food()
        If snake(0).X = foodPointX And snake(0).Y = foodPointY Then
            ReDim Preserve snake(snake.Length)
            foodPointX = randF.Next(0, 32)
            foodPointY = randF.Next(0, 32)
            boxArray(foodPointX, foodPointY).BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBoundsAndMovement()
        For i As Integer = 0 To snake.GetUpperBound(0)
            boxArray(snake(i).X, snake(i).Y).BackColor = Color.White 'Loop to change the whole snake white
            boxArray(snake(i).X, snake(i).Y).Update()
        Next
        If snake.Length > 1 Then
            For i As Integer = snake.GetUpperBound(0) To 1 Step -1
                snake(i) = snake(i - 1)
            Next
        End If
        snake(0) = snake(0) + direction
        If snake(0).X > playMaxWidth Then
            snake(0).X -= (playMaxWidth + 1)
        End If
        If snake(0).X < 0 Then
            snake(0).X += (playMaxWidth + 1)
        End If                                                       'Four If statements to check if the snake has gone outside the play area.
        If snake(0).Y > playMaxWidth Then
            snake(0).Y -= (playMaxWidth + 1)
        End If
        If snake(0).Y < 0 Then
            snake(0).Y += (playMaxWidth + 1)
        End If
        For k As Integer = 0 To snake.GetUpperBound(0)
            boxArray(snake(k).X, snake(k).Y).BackColor = Color.Black 'Loop to make the whole snake black
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub timGameTick_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timGameTick.Tick
        Food()
        CheckBoundsAndMovement()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmPlayfield_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown 'Subroutine for direction
        Select Case (e.KeyCode)
            Case Keys.Up
                direction = New Point(0, -1)
            Case Keys.Down
                direction = New Point(0, 1)
            Case Keys.Left
                direction = New Point(-1, 0)
            Case Keys.Right
                direction = New Point(1, 0)
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```